# MySQL left join not counting correctly

Tags: mysql

I've currently got two tables, one contains budget information and the other is for each row in the budgets. I'm trying to select the information from the budget table, and also get the amount of rows in each budget. My current SQL is:

```
SELECT actual.ActualID, DateReceived, DateStart, DateEnd, ActualTotal, count(SchActualID) as NumberOfSch 
FROM actual 
LEFT JOIN schactual on actual.ActualID = schactual.ActualID 
where CentreID = 29 order by DateEnd DESC
```

I thought that it worked as intended, but it appears that it doesn't count the correct value. The schactual table has 4 rows in it at the moment, only one of which contains the ActualID 29, but if I run the above query the NumberOfSch is 3. Any ideas into what I'm doing wrong here?

Example input: 
centreID = 29

Or

centreID = 30

Example output:
Say I run the query as above, it has one budget in the actual table, with a single schedule in the schActual table. The expected output would be:

**ActualID | DateReceived | DateStart | DateEnd | ActualTotal | NumberOfSch**

24    | 2014-11-02   |  2013-03-31 | 2014-03-31 | 1000 | 1

Current output is:

**ActualID | DateReceived | DateStart | DateEnd | ActualTotal | NumberOfSch**

24    | 2014-11-02   |  2013-03-31 | 2014-03-31 | 1000 | **2**

The table structure looks like this:
Actual:

- ActualID (PK)
- CentreID (FK)
- DateReceived
- Date Start
- DateEnd
- ActualTotal

SchActual:

- SchActualID (PK)
- ActualID (FK)
- SchNo
- SchName
- Fees
- etc..

Comment: try `COUNT(DISTINCT SchActualID)`

Comment: aggregate function without `group by` ?

Comment: @SBH Same result I'm afraid.

Comment: is it CentreID or ActualID has the value 29?

Comment: Could you post some sample input and the expected output?

Comment: @YohanesKhosiawan许先汉 CentreID has the value of 29. Each budget has it's own ID (ActualID) and each schedule (row in the budget) has it's own ID (SchActualID).

Comment: we need your sample of input and output as well, @pyy

Comment: @YohanesKhosiawan许先汉 Sorry that took a while for me to work out the formatting, I kind of gave up in the end. Is that what you needed?

Comment: we need the content (a few rows) of both tables

Comment: @YohanesKhosiawan许先汉 How is that?

Comment: I' have a feeling you need inner join instead if you want to exactly count by actualId. Because now you may have null which is counted too.

Comment: @bksi I started off with an inner join on this query, but even if I change it, it still gives me the exact same result. There are no nulls in the table, the above sample information is everything from both tables at present.

Comment: Can you put SchActualID in the query as a column and show the result?

Comment: @bksi If I was to run the query (with centreID being 29) and add SchActualID in as a column, it returns one row withSchActualID being 2.

Comment: I think it's fine, can you clarify whether the result here is the one that you want? http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a0f3af/5

Comment: @YohanesKhosiawan许先汉 If I was to run that SQL statement against my database and add in the other rows, this is what I'm getting: http://i.imgur.com/ed1IbI0.png The output I'm after is having each of the actualIDs in a separate row with the count of NumberOfSch being the number of items in SchActual with that ActualID.

Comment: then, try to use group by: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a0f3af/8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you just need to add group by to that query, and you are good to go.

Here is partial query of yours to simplify the solution:

**UPDATED**:

```
SELECT actual.actualid, count(schactualid) AS NumberOfSch 
FROM actual 
LEFT JOIN schactual on actual.actualid = schactual.actualid 
WHERE centreid = 29
GROUP BY actual.actualid
```

SQLFiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a0f3af/8